# Use variable in another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I would like to use the variable `lastChanged` inside `_Body` inside `_ListItem`. Unfortunately `lastChanged` does not recognized by `_ListItem`.

How could I use my varaible e.g. `lastChanged` inside the `_ListItem`.

If am using `static` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61116817/17136258) `static String settingVersion = "";` I can not use `setState`

```dart
class SettingRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SettingRoute> createState() => _SettingRoute();
}

class _SettingRoute extends State<SettingRoute> {

  String settingVersion = "";
  String lastChanged = "";
  String tagVersionDriving = "";
  String tagVersionParking = "";
  bool defaultTagDriving = true;
  bool defaultTagParking = true;
  List<Label> labels = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: _Body(),
      bottomNavigationBar: _PageButton(),
    );
  }
}

class _Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Body();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => const _ListItem(),
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              itemCount: 3,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ListItem();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        border: Border.all(),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print("click");
                }
              },
              leading: const Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              title: Text("Setting Version"),
              subtitle: Text("$settingVersion"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print("click");
                }
              },
              leading: const Icon(
                Icons.access_time,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              title: Text("Last change of the tag-version"),
              subtitle: Text("$lastChanged"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const _PageButton();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text("Some Button"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can either declare that as a TextEditingController in a new file and access and modify it using the properties of TextEditingController OR you can declare the variable outside of any class in your file and access it within that file OR you can pass the value to the desired class with the help of constructors

Comment: @NaqeebAbid and what is the best option, when working with `setState` ?

Comment: To me, it would be using a separate file containing the TEC, it just works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it down as parameters of the constructors, like

```
class _SettingRoute extends State<SettingRoute> {

  String settingVersion = "";
  String lastChanged = "";
  String tagVersionDriving = "";
  String tagVersionParking = "";
  bool defaultTagDriving = true;
  bool defaultTagParking = true;
  List<Label> labels = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _Body(settingVersion, lastChanged),
      bottomNavigationBar: const _PageButton(),
    );
  }
}

class _Body extends StatelessWidget {
  final String settingVersion;
  final String lastChanged;
  const _Body(this.settingVersion, this.lastChanged);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => _ListItem(settingVersion, lastChanged),
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              itemCount: 3,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String settingVersion;
  final String lastChanged;
  const _ListItem(this.settingVersion, this.lastChanged);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        border: Border.all(),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print("click");
                }
              },
              leading: const Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              title: Text("Setting Version"),
              subtitle: Text("$settingVersion"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                if (kDebugMode) {
                  print("click");
                }
              },
              leading: const Icon(
                Icons.access_time,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
              title: Text("Last change of the tag-version"),
              subtitle: Text("$lastChanged"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Although it feels to me you are splitting it too much up into different `StatelessWidget`s. If you are not going to reuse them you might as well just make it all part of `SettingRoute`, then you also don't have that problem